# Proof that bin packing is strongly NP-complete?

Tags: complexity-theory, np-complete

Wikipedia claims that bin packing is strongly NP-complete. Unfortunately I haven't been able to find a proof. Does anyone know where to find it?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Such a proof is outlined in Garey and Johnson, ['Strong' NP-Completeness Results: Motivation, Examples, and Implications](http://doi.acm.org/10.1145/322077.322090), mentioned in the Wikipedia article. The proof is by a straightforward reduction from 3-PARTITION. The problem 3-PARTITION one is given $3n$ numbers, and the task is to decide whether they can be split into triples of equal sum. There is a straightforward reduction from 3-PARTITION to BIN-PACKING: if the sum of the numbers is $nB$, ask whether the $3n$ numbers can be packed into $n$ bins of size $B$.

The strong NP-completeness of 3-PARTITION was proved in a different paper of Garey and Johnson, [Complexity results for multiprocessor scheduling under resource constraints](http://epubs.siam.org/doi/abs/10.1137/0204035). The proof is quite long, ultimately a reduction from 3DM (3-dimensional matching), but going through many intermediate steps.